# Asus EeePC 701sd windows 7

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a Asus EeePC 701sd and upgraded to Win 7 Ultimate but I couldn't find any driver for the wireless network adapter. Does anyone knows where I can find it?
please help! thanks :(

Answer (score 0):

You can find that driver and all other drivers [here](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=Eee%20PC%20701SD/XP&os=17) under the `wireless` node

It appears however that ASUS only officially supports windows XP and linux for your particular model. You may not be able to run windows 7 on that machine, however I would try and install the driver anyways just to make sure.

[image]